# Animate snap in ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2, qt5.3

I would like to animate the "snap" effect when a [`ListView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html) snaps to a specific item.

I enable "snapping" with the `snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem` property. Currently it just de-accelerates to the current item and stops, but it would be nice if I could get it to make a "bounce" effect when it stops.

Any ideas about how I can do this?

`Flickable` has a [`rebound`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#rebound-prop) property, but this seems to not work for the snapping on elements inside a `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used `SnapOneItem`, you can insert a bounce effect once the movement is finished, i.e. once [`movementEnded`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#movementEnded-signal) signal is emitted. IMO applying an animation on each item would be overkill in this case. Better would be to animate the [`contentY`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#contentY-prop) property of the `ListView`.

The following is a possible approach which produces a bounce (don't know if this is the exact effect you are searching for):

```
ListView {
    id: list
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 10
    snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
    model: 100

    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: 50
        Text {                // added text to distinguish items
            text: index
            font.pixelSize: 20
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
        color: index % 2 ? "lightGray" : "darkGrey"
    }

    onMovementEnded: {
        bounce.start()        // starts the animation when the movement ends
    }

    onCurrentIndexChanged: { 
        if(!list.moving)      // animation started only if the list is not moving
            bounce.start()
    }

    Timer {
        repeat: true
        interval: 2000     // enough time to let the animation play
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            list.incrementCurrentIndex()
        }
    }

    SequentialAnimation {
        id: bounce
        running: false

        NumberAnimation {
            target: list
            property: "contentY"
            to: list.contentY - 10
            easing {
                type: Easing.InOutBack
                amplitude: 2.0
                period: 0.5
            }
            duration: 250
        }

        NumberAnimation {
            target: list
            property: "contentY"
            to: list.contentY
            duration: 800
            easing {
                type: Easing.OutBounce
                amplitude: 3.0
                period: 0.7
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you release the items from a drag or movement the bounce is produced. The `amplitude` and `period` properties can be adjusted to obtain a stronger or lighter effect (the same applies for the value of `to` properties).

### EDIT

As you've seen, if the list is moved via `incrementCurrentIndex()` no real movement occurs, i.e. the `movementEnded` signal is not emitted. In such a case you can exploit the change of value that occurs for the `currentIndex`. I've modified the example to combine this approach with the previous one and to show the usage I've inserted a `Timer` to call `incrementCurrentIndex()` function.

The `!list.moving` check is added to avoid double animations when the list is moved and to guarantee consistency in the example, since the `Timer` can generate inconsistent jumps while the list is dragged. Clearly, other more specific constraints can be added, depending on your requirements.